# How do you enumerate though .getGroups() in Opendege?

Tags: .net, openedge

I'm trying to correctly enumerate through the groups I have, using .net call for Active Directory.

I have my group object coming back if I message it out like so.

```
USING System.Security.Principal.*.
USING System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.*.
USING System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.

DEFINE VARIABLE networkPrincipalContextCls AS CLASS PrincipalContext NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE nPrincipalUserCls AS CLASS UserPrincipal NO-UNDO.

nPrincipalUserCls = NEW UserPrincipal(networkPrincipalContextCls).
MESSAGE UserPrincipal:FindByIdentity(networkPrincipalContextCls,User):GetGroups() VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

I've been googling and looking that the progress knowledge resources. I cannot find an example or explanation on how to do this. If anyone knows of any resources I can look at or has a example that will get me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of OpenEdge?

Comment: @TomBascom     I am using OE 11.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, which type the items in the result of GetGroups() are, but something like this, based on foreach.i: https://github.com/consultingwerk/ListsAndEnumSamples/blob/master/Consultingwerk/foreach.i

```
oGroups = UserPrincipal:FindByIdentity(networkPrincipalContextCls,User):GetGroups() .
{Consultingwerk/foreach.i Principal oItem in oGroups}
    MESSAGE oItem:ToString() .
END.
```

Comment: @ mikefechner  What are you defining oGroups as?